# How to show v-tooltip only when button is disabled

Tags: vue.js, v-tooltip

I am using Vuejs 2 and the v-tooltip npm package. I would like to display the v-tooltip only when a button is disabled. When it is not disabled, I don't want to display the v-tooltip at all.

```
<button
  v-tooltip="message"
  :disabled="true">
  CLICK ME!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have a variable `disabled` in your state, it can be a condition as well `a > b`, then you can conditionally render the buttons.

```
<button
  v-if="disabled"
  v-tooltip="message"
  :disabled="true">
  CLICK ME!
</button>
<button
  v-else
>
  CLICK ME!
</button>
```

Or you can even try this

```
<button
  v-tooltip="disabled ? message : ''"
  :disabled="true">
  CLICK ME!
</button>
```

maybe it will work